# How to simplify complicated conditional clauses when using LINQ to SQL

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql, refactoring

Complicated statements with lots of AND/OR compenents are horrible to read and prone to errors - in a normal IF statement I might make use of a method call to simplify the is statement - for example:

```
        if (((user == myUser || user == yourUser) && user != Admin)
            && Something > SomethingElse
            && (thresholdDate > item.itemDate || (item.itemDate == null && item.itemType == itemIsDated))
            )
        {
            DoStuff();
        }
```

I could refactor out the user and date parts to make things easier to read:

```
        if (
            UserValid(user)
            && Something > SomethingElse
            && DateIsValid(thresholdDate, item)
           )
        {
            DoStuff();
        }
```

What can I do in a LINQ query to simplifiy the nested IF?

For example if I have something along the lines of:

```
        var someResults = DataManager.Things
                                        .Where(item => (item.UserName == currentUser.UserName
                                                        || item.ParentUsername == currentUser.UserName)
                                                       && (item.ItemType == (int) ItemType.MyType
                                                           || item.ItemType == (int) ItemType.YourType)
                                                       && item.Result == null
                                                       && (
                                                              (item.Status == null
                                                               && (item.ItemDate < thresholdDate
                                                                   || item.ItemType == (int) ItemType.YourType)
                                                              )
                                                              ||
                                                              (item.Status != null &&
                                                               item.Status != "Rejected")
                                                          )
            )
```

** not actual code - just a simplified and generic example.

I'd like to be able to extract parts of the logic into methods - or in some other way seperate out the AND / OR mess such that it's clear what is going on.

I've tried adding a method to the 'item' to perfrom some of the logic a kind of IsValidType(typeOptions) method - this compiles fine but LINQ complains that it does't recognise the method at runtime.

I could use a property on the item - but then I can't pass any context information (which makes it of limited use)

How do you go about making this kind of query readable?

Comment: If it's Linq-To-Sql tag it accordingly because in Linq-To-Objects it's no problem to use methods.

Comment: @TimSchmelter - good point - amended

Answer (score 0):

As Tim mentioned in a comment, you can use methods in most LINQ-to-something implementations.
The result would look like this:

```
.Where(item => CheckUserName(item)
    && CheckItemType(item)
    && CheckItemResult(item)
    && CheckItemStatus(item));
```

In case of LINQ to SQL, LINQ to Entities or other remote-executed implementations, you can at least take advantage of query optimization and rewrite all `&&` to separate `Where` calls, because they are equivalent:

```
.Where(item => item.UserName == currentUser.UserName
    || item.ParentUsername == currentUser.UserName)
.Where(item => item.ItemType == (int) ItemType.MyType
    || item.ItemType == (int) ItemType.YourType)
.Where(item => item.Result == null)
.Where(item => (item.Status == null
    && (item.ItemDate < thresholdDate
        || item.ItemType == (int) ItemType.YourType))
    || (item.Status != null
        && item.Status != "Rejected"));
```

The resulting query will join the where clauses into one enumerator.

Comment: I think this is a step in the right direction - but it's still pretty difficult to see what's going on... it would be worse if the bottom level operator was 'OR' because this technique wouldn't help at all. The LINQ-to-gubbins version is much easier to read and each of the methods can have simple, testable condition in them and so it's easy to verify that the results are correct. Is there no way to get this seperation with LINQ-to-SQL?

Comment: I am not sure, because the whole query gets translated to SQL and is executed in the DB engine, not in your app's memory. If you can afford it, you might do only simple checks in this query, retrieve more items and then do complex conditions on the retrieved data in-memory using methods. But this means more traffic between your app and the DB, and also more memory consumption of your app (because it has to hold the large intermediate result)

Answer (score 0):

I assume you can't do it directly in your code. Of course if you had plenty of similar conditions, you could generate the expression for them dynamically. But you can do very little with single big Where condition here not hurting the performance =(.

If you consider it more appripriate, you could split your single big condition to few consequent Where() calls. LINQ tree when converting to SQL will merge conditions and generate single select. DBMS can also optimize the generated SQL for maximum efficiency. So you can in some cases intentionally write not optimized queries for better readability and rely on automatic optimizations. Though be careful with it and check if your specific conditions really gets merged and optimized as you expect.

If you can move this code to SQL stored procedure, you could configure LINQ to SQL to call this procedure when you need. That will simplify the calling code, but move complications to SQL. I suppose you can even extract some of your conditions to SQL functions and make them being called, using in the Where clause. Though to be honest I never used it - just read about possibility. For more details and example look at this article: http://weblogs.asp.net/zeeshanhirani/archive/2008/05/21/table-valued-functions-in-linq-to-sql.aspx

Comment: I think moving the conditional clauses to a stored procedure only shifts the problem into the DB. It may be possible to make the conditions easier to read there,  but I think the added level of complexity will only make readability worse because then you'd need to go poking about in the database to find out what's going on (and the same code might run against different databases so there may also be all kinds of other maintainance issues ensuring that the stored proc is in sync with the build)

Comment: Completely agree with that. But have you checked the last point with the link? It allows writing almost the same code you want in the C# and add few simple functions in SQL. ANyway it will need upgrades of DB, but simple functions tend to change rarely.

Comment: It's an interesting idea - but I'm concerned about moving logic to the DB as this complicates the testing and readability - a developer coming to make a change would then need to dig through to find the bits of SQL being used and there's a risk of looking at the wrong dev database or something and getting confused. If it were systematic across the whole development it might be a plan, but in a individual case, although it makes the code slightly nicer it does so at the cost of quite a bit of additional complexity.

Answer (score 0):

Three very different options:

- Use [Resharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/). It contains a number of code inspections and refactorings to reduce if statements or point out redundant predicates.
- In linq-to-sql you can skip most check for `null`. That is because the expressions are translated into SQL and in SQL there is no null reference exception. A linq (to sql) clause like `where a.Name == "x"` just yields `false` when there is no `a`. In linq-to-objects this would throw a null reference exception.
- For comparisons that are done *really* often you may consider adding [computed columns](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191250%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) to your database tables. Like a column `IsRejected` that evaluates `Status = 'Rejected'`. In linq that would reduce to `where !item.IsRejected`.

Comment: I have the latest version of Resharper, but this kind of LINQ query is outside of the scope of any refactoring options I can find. The null checks in this case are not to prevent null reference exceptions but to filter for values that exist or don't exist - therefore these can't be removed without changing the meaning of the clause. Unless it was to address a significant performance issue, I'm not sure that moving sections of the logic to the DB is a good idea as this adds additonal complexity and maintainance concerns. The key is to make the LINQ easy to read, understand, and test.

Comment: In your example `item.Status != null && item.Status != "Rejected"` does the same as `item.Status != "Rejected"` (in sql!). But you're right that where you really need to check for `IS NULL` this should also be coded in linq. As for computed columns and maintenance concerns: that depends on the development environment. I know projects where the database is kept as "dead" as possible (with valid reasons). In such a context I would not recommend computed column indeed. But in other projects we greatly benefit from them.

Comment: True - that particular check could be simplified - that's the trouble with inventing examples ;) I guess that level of simplifcation is a good first step, but doesn't really address the wider requirement for a more readable and testable way to code complicated clauses. Isn't the computed column limited to the scope of the table? If so, it cannot handle any context data and so, other than in a possible performance variation I'm not sure how it's different from using a public property in c#. A property could be used to simplify the example slightly - but not to the same extent as object methods.

Comment: Yes it is scoped to the table and it can not be parametrized, but a useful difference with calculated c# properties is that the latter can not be translated into SQL by a linq-to-"database" provider. Entity framework will throw runtime exceptions when such properties are used in expressions.

Comment: Maybe we have a different version of .net? I'm using .net4 and I can use c# properties in a LINQ-to-SQL expression without issue. I can create a property along the lines of public bool IsRejected { get {return Status!="rejected"; } } to get a similar effect. (although I'm not sure if this is evaluated in SQL or in code - so the performance difference could be significant in some cases)

Comment: Linq-to-sql is more permissive here, but that is because it decides for itself when to switch to linq-to-objects (which sometimes can cause undesired side effects, probably a reason why EF is stricter). You will never find a c# property in SQL emitted by L2S.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19897/discussion-between-tyco-kaine-and-gert-arnold)